# Android: UI freezes when intent calls a service

Tags: android

Hello I have an intent as below that starts a service

```
public void startAlarmService() {
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("me.application.AlarmService");
    startService(i);
}
```

This method is called when a checkbox is checked. However, when it gets checked, the UI freezes for like 5 seconds..

I tried to call the above method by running a new Thread, and then by using AsyncTask but both didn't work and it took also like 5 seconds to run since for example I put a progress dialog and the UI froze before showing the progress dialog.

How can I make sure that the UI does not freeze on start this service?

Thank you for you help.

Edit: Service Code: Download part using async task:

```
asyncDownload aCall = new asyncDownload(getApplicationContext(),this);              
boolean result = aCall.execute().get();
return result;
```

Comment: Is there a valid Service that handles actions with this name?

Comment: yea of course and the service runs as expected.

Comment: What exactly do you do in that service? An extension of the `Service` class runs on the main UI thread.

Comment: i download an image but i use async task to do this:
Code above updated.

Comment: and yes there is a valid asyncTask class and also runs as expected @Luksprog

Comment: Remove the `aCall.execute().get()` line( http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get%28%29 ) and see if that makes a difference. Also make sure you don't do stuff on the UI thread in the `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Thank you @Luksprog sorry but got the answer below 1st :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are firstly creating an `AsyncTask` and later using it's `get()` method, which blocks main thread. Do it properly - background work in `doInBackground(Params...)`, then update UI in `onPostExecute(Result)`, which is called in main thread again - instead of using `get()`.

Comment: If i remove the get() it works perfectly.Thank you. But can you please tell me how to get the result value from the asyncTask To the Service if not by get? I need to know the result of the asyncTask in the Service. I need the value so i know if asyncTask succeeded in downloading the image. If not i need to reset the alarm service. Do i have to reset the alarm service in the OnPostExecute?

Answer (score 1):

By default a service run on the same thread as the activities of the same app, ie the UI thread.
So running your service in a new thread looks like a good solution.

Comment: Exactly, I think the problem is not the firing the service itself (above lines) in the main thread, but rather fact, that the service uses thread which it was created in by default - so service implementation.

Comment: but i used asyncTask to do the all the work. Isnt asyncTask an also correct thing to do? Also  I tried calling the service by running a new thread but also got the UI frozen @FenixVoltres

Comment: Yep, onExecute of an AsyncTask run in a separate thread but I don't know what your service does outside of the AsyncTask. I am just pointing at the most likely problem.
Simple test to confirm/infirm. create a new service that only do Log.d("TAG", "service created");
and replace your service by this one.